# Stream an IP camera video using Raspberry Pi as stream server and access it from remote networks

Tags: pi-2, streaming-video, java

I have been working on a IoT project for some time. I have an IP camera and I want to make a Raspberry Pi work as a stream server to stream the IP camera and access it in a browser.

I have found a number of projects doing the same thing with the Raspberry Pi camera module or USB webcam, but I want to know if it's possible to do that with a generic IP camera (in my case HiKam IPcamera).

Answer (score -3):

It's possible. UV4L can do exactly what you want.

Here are the detailed instructions: [Turn any MJPEG streaming source (e.g. IP camera) into a virtual camera](http://www.linux-projects.org/uv4l/tutorials/turn-mjpeg-stream-into-camera/).

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged across StackExchange. The other end of the link is subject to change, deletion or a multitude of other undesirable outcomes. Please outline the relevant points in your posted answer.

Comment: In keeping with our [policy regarding informationless link-only answers](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538), if this post is not edited to contain information that can stand as an answer, however minimal, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community.

Comment: don't be victim of your stupid rules. I do not know why the answer has been downvoted, but I wonder if those who did have better answers.

Comment: Did you read the linked meta post that covers the rationale behind this idea? This is not about *stupid rules* but about answers that stand on their own should that link die.

Comment: First of all, that is not a link-only answer, as there is also the indication of the name of the software program and it s hard to see how anything else would be on topic: simple answer to a simple question. Secondly, has been proven to be adequate to the OP - see his positive feedback. Thirdly, I still do not see any other alternative answer, very likely because there are no alternatives. Again, take your rules with a grain of salt and thank the people who spend their time trying to be useful to others.